# What would be the performance difference with largeTable setting to be true versus false

Tags: optimization, itext7

I'm trying to optimize my application's performance for generating PDF document in .NET Core with C#. In local testing, I noticed that when I use the Table constructor with a second parameter of `largeTable = true`, it shortens the timing by 5% to 15%. What's the reason behind it?

Comment: Please add your code to reproduce. In general large tables are meant to provide more performant functionality, but for that you need to write helper code to flush the contents once in a while

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for the comments. When you say "to flush the contents once in a while", do you mean flush it to the physical file? If yes, I'm trying to avoid generating physical file as this application is a web application. I'm trying to generate in memory so that we don't have to store it temporarily on the server and clean it afterwards.

Comment: Flushing is performed to the output stream associated with your document, totally depends on how you create it